# Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt cannot see program from PATH

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmd, path

I installed new Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, Visual C++ 2008 for Python 2.7, Miniconda 2, Miktex, Iron Python 2.7.5 and everything is in PATH in env variables.

In normal CMD.exe I can do:

```
C:\Users\robgr>pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
**
C:\Users\robgr>ipy64
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z

C:\Users\robgr>conda
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] [--debug] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.
```

But in Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt I got:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x64 tools.
C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7>pdflatex
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7>ipy64
'ipy64' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7>conda
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] [--debug] command ...
```

But before everythin worked fine...

What may be the problem here?

EDIT:

"`Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt`" has command : `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat" amd64"`

Path to "conda" : `Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda.exe`
Path to conda Python env "python27a" : `Q:\Python\Miniconda2\envs\python27a`
Path to IronPython "ipy64" : `Q:\Python\IronPython\ipy64.exe`
Path to "pdflatex" : `Q:\LaTex\MiKTeX\v2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe`

PATH in global envs:

```
T:\Microsoft\Solver Foundation\3.0.2.10889\Plugins;
C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\envs\python27a\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;
Q:\C\PCL\v1.6.0\bin;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Scripts;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Library\bin;
D:\Internet\WinSCP\WinSCP;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5;
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP;
U:\MATLAB\R2015a\runtime\win64;
U:\MATLAB\R2015a\bin;
U:\MATLAB\R2015a\polyspace\bin;
C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass;
Q:\Python\IronPython;
Q:\Python\IronPython\ipy64.exe;
Q:\LaTex\MiKTeX\v2.9\miktex\bin\x64;
D:\System\Git\cmd`
```

PATH seen in vcpp 2008 cmd:

```
C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7>echo %PATH%

C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64;
C:\Users\robgr\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Bin;
T:\Microsoft\Solver Foundation\3.0.2.10889\Plugins;
C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\envs\python27a\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;
Q:\C\PCL\v1.6.0\bin;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Scripts;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Library\bin;
D:\Internet\WinSCP\WinSCP;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4
```

PATH seen in normal cmd:

```
C:\Users\robgr>echo %PATH%

T:\Microsoft\Solver Foundation\3.0.2.10889\Plugins;
C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\envs\python27a\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;
Q:\C\PCL\v1.6.0\bin;
C:\Users\robgr\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;
Q:\Haskel\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin;
Q:\Haskel\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Scripts;
Q:\Python\Miniconda2\Library\bin;
D:\Internet\WinSCP\WinSCP;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4
```

Comment: The & character in the MySQL directory name appears to have an unpleasant side-effect of truncating the path.  Hard to guess why, consider eliminating them.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe -.- MySQL was bugging in PATH:

c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5
c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP

And when I opened vcpp 2008 cmd there was...

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x64 cross tools.
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But this part "`'MySQL' is not recognized` " I was neglecting as non important (in previous windows was at end in PATH), so I was removing it from question in this post... But the this is that this sign "&" if included in PATH is acting as separate command. So this was making bug.

When I remove this sign "&" from PATH or path containing this "&" its working now :)